# Confusing mixed geometry error in ST_Clip with raster and MultiPolygon

Tags: postgis

I'm getting an error about an operation on mixed geometries coming from a use of ST_Clip(raster, geometry). All the tables involved are uniformly SRID 4326 but maybe it's coming from an empty raster (a clip of a clip)? Any ideas for what is causing this or how to figure it out would be very welcome!

Here's the query:

```
select "name1", "name2",
       sum("areal_overlap_wgt" * "tract_pop") as "areal_overlap_pop",
       sum("dasymmetric_overlap_wgt" * "tract_pop") as "dasymmetric_overlap_pop",
       sum("dasymmetric_wgt" * "tract_pop") as "dasymmetric_pop"
from (
    select "name1", "name2", "tract_pop",
           case
            when "tract_area" > 0
            then "tract_area_in_both" / "tract_area"
            else 0
           end as "areal_overlap_wgt",
           case
            when "dev_in_tract" > 0
            then "dev_in_tract_s1_s2" / "dev_in_tract"
            else 0
           end as "dasymmetric_overlap_wgt",
           case
            when "dev_in_tract" > 0
            then "dev_in_tract_s1" / "dev_in_tract"
            else 0
           end as "dasymmetric_wgt"
    from (
        select "name1", "name2", "tract_pop",
               ST_AREA("tract_geom" :: geography) as "tract_area",
               ST_AREA(ST_INTERSECTION("tract_in_s1", "geom2") :: geography) as "tract_area_in_both",
               coalesce(ST_VALUECOUNT(ST_UNION("rast_in_tract"),1,true,1), 0)   as "dev_in_tract",
               coalesce(ST_VALUECOUNT(ST_UNION(ST_CLIP("rast_in_tract", "geom1", true)),1,true,1), 0)   as "dev_in_tract_s1",
               coalesce(ST_VALUECOUNT(ST_UNION(ST_CLIP(ST_CLIP("rast_in_tract", "geom1", true), "geom2", true)),1,true,1), 0)   as "dev_in_tract_s1_s2"
        from (
            select s1."name" as "name1",
                   s1."geometry" as "geom1",
                   s2."name" as "name2",
                   s2."geometry" as "geom2",
                   t."geom" as "tract_geom",
                   t."AQNFE001" as "tract_pop",
                   ST_INTERSECTION(s1."geometry", t."geom") as "tract_in_s1",
                   ST_INTERSECTION(ST_INTERSECTION(s1."geometry", s2."geometry"), t."geom") as "tract_in_both",
                   ST_CLIP(r."rast", t."geom", true) as "rast_in_tract"
            from "co_sldu" s1
            inner join "co_cd" s2 on s1."geometry" && s2."geometry"
            inner join "tracts2022_acs2017_2022" t on s1."geometry" && t."geom"
            inner join "nlcd_us_dev" r on t."geom" && r."rast"
        )
        where (not ST_ISEMPTY("rast_in_tract"))
        group by "name1", "name2", "geom2", "tract_pop", "tract_geom", "tract_in_s1"

    )
)
group by "name1", "name2"
```

and the error (from python which is sending that query):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/adam/BlueRipple/GeoData/code/areal.py", line 329, in <module>
    cur.execute(overlap_sql)
psycopg2.errors.InternalError_: contains: Operation on mixed SRID geometries (MultiPolygon, 4326) != (Point, 0)
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function st_clip(raster,integer[],geometry,double precision[],boolean) line 4 at IF
```

Comment: Try setting the srid on your inner clip `ST_SETSRID(ST_CLIP(r."rast", t."geom", true),4326) as "rast_in_tract"`